# smarty section loop

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to get a loop for following...

```
{$product.min_val} //2
{$product.max_val} //8
```

and i am trying following...

```
{section name=val start=$product.min_val loop=$product.max_val step=0}
<p id="{$smarty.section.val.index}">{$smarty.section.val.index}</p>
{/section}
```

it prints following...

```
<p id="2">2</p>
<p id="3">3</p>
<p id="4">4</p>
<p id="5">5</p>
<p id="6">6</p>
<p id="7">7</p>
```

You might have noticed that its missing `<p id="8">8</p>` according to `{$product.max_val}`
 thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Loop*** is the number of times the section will loop, so you need:

```
{section name=val start=$product.min_val loop=$product.max_val+1}
<p id="{$smarty.section.val.index}">{$smarty.section.val.index}</p>
{/section}
```

Comment: Actually, `loop` is the number of times it runs, not the `max` bound: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl

Answer (score 0):

While the output is strange, your input is strange too. Firstly, I assume you want to print the following values:

2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8; these are 7 numbers

So indeed, `start` is right and must be `2`. However, `loop` must be `7`, or more general `$product.max_val - $product.min_val + 1`. And a step size of `0` is just strange altogether.

This should work:

```
{section name=val start=$product.min_val loop=($product.max_val - $product.min_val + 1) step=1}
  <p id="{$smarty.section.val.index}">{$smarty.section.val.index}</p>
{/section}
```

Though your use of `val` is somewhat off I think. It should be used as an index instead.